# JCheckBox setting values in other class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcheckbox

Hello I have something like this

```
public class GUI{
    public JCheckBox box;
    public boolean value;

    void init(){
        box.addActionListener(new BoxListener(this));
    }
}

public class BoxListener implements ActionListener{
    GUI gui;
    public BoxListener(GUI gui){
         this.gui = gui;
    }

    @override
    public void actionperformed(ActionEvent a){
         gui.value = true; 
    }

}
```

Now I want to change the value of the bool when the checkbox gets clicked.
I am looking for better solutions than to pass Class GUI as input parameter for a self written listener.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: There are tons of examples on how to do this. Try and google it!

Comment: Why do you need to pass `A` as a parameter? I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Because the actionlistener on the box don't know anything about the GUI.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  And use meaningful class and member names. Class `A` does not give enough context to provide good advice.

Comment: I think one crucial point is what bblincoe already suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21629632 : Why should the boolean value be stored in the GUI, when the value is directly linked (and probably always equal) to the state of the check box? Shouldn't this boolean be part of a *Model* somehow?

Comment: Just think of you have a checkbox in one class and if the user checks it, something in another class shall happen

Comment: @Gobliins That's exactly what a Listener does! Simply implement the `itemStateChanged` method of your `ItemListener`.

Comment: @Gobliins Then the fact that this value resided in the GUI in your example may have been unfortunate. Of course, when this is a boolean value in "any" class, then it is desirable to NOT link this particular class to the listener by passing in a reference. Usually, you should consider MVC, as peeskillet suggested. A pragmatic alternative could be a "single method interface" like http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html , that "wraps" away the call to `specificClass.setBoolean(true)`, so that the listener only knows a `Consumer` and calls `consumer.consume(true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would throw in some MVC it's a lot more work, but it makes for more flexible coding.

First a `ModelBean` with a `boolean checked` and `propertyChangeSupport` for firing property change events

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ModelBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean checked;

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public ModelBean() {
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        boolean oldValue = this.checked;
        this.checked = checked;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange("checked", oldValue, this.checked);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }  
}
```

Then you have your main `GUI` class that takes the `ModelBean` as an argument

```
class GUI extends JFrame {
    private ModelBean model;
    private JCheckBox cbox;

    public GUI(ModelBean model) {
        this.model = model;
        cbox = new JCheckBox("Check and watch me print");
        cbox.addItemListener(new CheckListener(model));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(cbox);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And you `ItemListener` class that takes the same `ModelBean` as an argument and also adds the `PropertyChangeListener` to the `model`

```
class CheckListener implements ItemListener {

    private ModelBean model;

    public CheckListener(ModelBean newModel) {
        this.model = newModel;
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println(model.getChecked());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        JCheckBox source = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
        if (source.isSelected()) {
            model.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            model.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you class to run the program

```
public class TestMVC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final ModelBean model = new ModelBean();
                GUI gui = new GUI(model);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It seems like a lot of work just for a silly `boolean` but the concept is a better overall design for larger programs where a lot of different data needs to be manipulated and listened to for changes.

---

**UPDATE**

Another option, if your GUI is the parent container, and you don't want to expose it by passing it by reference, you can create an `interface` and have `GUI` implement it

```
public interface BooleanInterface {
    public void setBoolean(boolean bool);
}

public class GUI extends JFrame implements BooleanInterface {
    boolean bool;

    @Override
    public void setBoolean(boolean bool) {
        this.bool = bool;
    }
}

public BoxListener implements ActionListener {
    BooleanInterface boolFace;

    public BoxListener(BooleanInterface boolFace) {
        this.boolFace = boolFace;
    }
}
```

You can then pass the `GUI` to the listener. Though it looks the same as what you're already doing, it actually *isn't*, since it no longer exposes the `GUI`, instead uses the interface.

Comment: Yes MVC is most of the time a good design. But like said, just all this implementation for setting a bool. i thoought there was maybe a quicker (even when more dirty) hack.

Comment: @Goblin you don't necessarily need to `PropertyChangeSupport`, I just added that in. You can just simply have class with the boolean, getter and setter and share the same class. I mean the way you are doing _is_ a hack but the thing it it exposes your GUI unnecessarily

Comment: @Goblins See my **UPDATE**. That is another solution, as to not expose the `GUI`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we take what you have and modify it slightly:

First, create a **Controller** (`DefaultController`) class that will handle initializing the application and will hold a reference to the GUI (or **View**)

```
public class DefaultController
{
    private final GUI view = new GUI(); // The view

    private void init()
    {
        // ...

        this.view.addBoxListener(new BoxListener(this.view));

        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // ... Start up code ...
    }
}
```

Next, modify your `GUI` class to include methods for interacting with the `JCheckBox` and register a listener:

```
public class GUI
{
    private JCheckBox box;

    // ...

    public void addBoxListener(ItemListener listener)
    {
        box.addItemListener(listener);
    }

    public void setBoxValue(boolean selected)
    {
        box.setSelected(selected);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now your `BoxListener` has an instance of the view (`GUI`) and can make calls to set the checkbox's value through the interface provided. You are no longer accessing the `box` member variable directly (encapsulation). This will allow you to make changes to the `setBoxValue` method without impacting the caller.

In your `BoxListener` class:

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt)
{
    view.setBoxValue(true); // For example...
}
```

Note: `view` is a member variable of `BoxListener` - `private GUI view;`

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as my current solution?

Comment: @Gobliins Not quite. First off, your solution does not use encapsulation (you should avoid `public` member variables. Second, a `Controller` class was introduced to handle registration between the `ActionListener`s and the `GUI` (read up on Model-View-Controller). The only part I didn't include was the `Model` in this solution.